# Bad API Key response | PHP

Tags: php, api

I keep getting "Bad API Key" response while the same API key is working fine without a problem in Postman

Here is my code

```
$apiKey ='MY API KEY';

$url = "MY URL";

$client = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($client,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
//curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: ' . $apiKey));
//curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-API-Key: $apiKey"));

$response = curl_exec($client);

$result = json_decode($response);

print_r($result);
```

Comment: We have no idea what API you're calling, how it works/expects or what you did in Postman.

Comment: What I find interesting is that you set `CURLOPT_USERPWD`, which basically sets an `Authorization` header of type `Basic`. Then you immediately overwrite it with `CURLOPT_HEADER` to set it to your API key. Without details about the things @M.Eriksson mentioned, we have no way of knowing whether that is an issue or if that is the correct way to call the API.

Comment: @rickdenhaan I forgot to comment the line of CURLOPT_USERPWD because username and password are sent through the url, as for the API, it is a local API that is only working on our server

Comment: @M.Eriksson I forgot to comment the line of CURLOPT_USERPWD because username and password are sent through the url, as for the API, it is a local API that is only working on our server

Comment: That still doesn't tell us anything about how the API you're trying to call works. We can't possibly see what the issue with your request is unless we know _exactly_ how the API works and what it expects. We're not here to play guessing games.

Answer (score 0):

The `authorization` header normally comes in different "flavors", or [authorization schemes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication#authentication_schemes). Since you are sending a token, I expect you want to send a `Bearer` request (which is handled automatically by Postman, if you are using the integrated authorization feature). So you have to slightly adapt your `curl_setopt`:

```
curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $apiKey));
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this scheme before and still the problem is persistent

Comment: Alright. Then please provide further information as @M.Eriksson pointed out.

Comment: Actually, there is no further information I can provide, the API is local on our server and not public, username and password are sent in the URL and I forgot to comment the line that authenticates username and password

Comment: Well for starters, you could show us what your _working_ Postman request actually looks like. (Or use the option it provides, to create PHP cURL code out of your request, to begin with.)